# adding arguments to a function call in llvm

Tags: arguments, llvm, function-calls

After having a look at the API in llvm::CallInst , I don't see a 
simple way to add any arguments to a function call that has already been generated.

Apart from creating a new function call , is there any other way to add 
arguments ?

Thanks!